# docker logs filebeat > file.log don't work

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, filebeat, ubuntu-19.04

With Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056 and filebeat:7.1.1 (by elasticsearch) when I type:

```
$ docker logs filebeat > filebeat.log
```

I see the logs but the filebeat.log is empty.

If I try:

```
$ docker logs logstash > logstash.log
```

I don't see the log to console but the file il full with the logs lines.

The used OS is: `Ubuntu 19.04`

Comment: What OS are you using? I just tested on Mac and it seems to work same for both images (can't imagine why it shouldn't)

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>` redirects STDOUT, but you can also have STDERR output from containers. To redirect that, you can use:

```
 docker logs filebeat > filebeat.log 2> filebeat.err
```

or send both to the same file:

```
 docker logs filebeat > filebeat.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run the container with the -t flag which will allocate a pseudo-tty for the container. Example:

`docker run -td --rm --name test store/elastic/filebeat:7.1.1`

`docker logs test > test.txt`

This will store the output to the file. When running without the -t flag it will simply dump the logs in your terminal